# Cytoscape does not run on Windows 11

Tags: cytoscape

I have succesfully installed Cytoscape 3.9.1 on my Windows 11 Laptop.
The Program does not start up tho, if I double-click it. Had the issue with older versions too.
Here is the output of the Cytoscape System Checker Script with all the information you need.

```
Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Windows
-------------------------------------------------

Target Cytoscape version: 3.9.0


Your Windows version is:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105]

Java is installed

More details on Java
--------------------

openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)


Your system is 64 bit

Your JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2

Your Java Major version is 11
Your Java version is at least version 11 as required

Your Java version is no higher than version 11 as required

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 51013    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0

The "app" store at https://apps.cytoscape.org is reachable



Summary
-------

Success! You are ready to run Cytoscape 3.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself by uninstalling all Java JDKs and JREs I had and then reinstalled Cytoscape (which then automatically installed the correct JDK too).